# Perl "->" operator

Tags: arrays, perl, syntax

Here's a piece of code:

```
foreach my $in (@_)
{
    my $x1 = sprintf("%.2f", $in->[0]);
    my $x2 = sprintf("%.2f", $in->[1]);
    my $x3 = sprintf("%.2f", $in->[2]);
    $count++;
    print "running: $x1 $x2 $x3\n";
    print PF "$x1 $x2 $x3\n";
}
```

I'm wondering what is the $in variable? Is it an array? Why we use $in->[0] instead of $in[0] here? How to get the length of $in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$in` is an array reference (so `@_` was an array of array references).

You get the number of elements (assuming that's what you mean by length) with `scalar(@$in)` (or just using `@$in` in scalar context).

Answer (score 3):

You can't nest arrays inside other structures in Perl.  You have to use a *reference* to an array, which is a scalar (so it uses `$`), and which needs `->` to get at the data.

Suffice to say it's a large topic that's kind of integral to any non-trivial Perl programming.  Give [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) a read.

Answer (score 1):

`$in` is a scalar holding reference of an `ARRAY`.

use `Data::Dumper` and check what is the content of `@_`. If they are the references, then in order to access them we use `->`.

In your code,

- `$in->[0]` would mean that you are accessing first element of array reference in `@_`.
- `$in->[1]` would mean that you are accessing second element of array reference in `@_`.
- `$in->[2]` would mean that you are accessing third element of array reference in `@_`.

Answer (score 0):

`$in` here is a [reference (similar to C pointers) to an array](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/perl-array-reference-examples/). So the `->` is used to dereference this reference to get at the array itself.